# How does Visual Studio find members?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, intellisense

I am looking for a resource that will help me open up the black box that is something along the lines of "Visual Studio intellisense class member lookup" (google has been failing me).

**The Situation**

I've got the following facts that don't seem to add up:

- I have a DLL to reference, `My.dll`, which contains a member, `My.Namespace.ValidationException`. Let's call the solution this is defined within `NugetPackage.sln`

[image: Dotpeek on the DLL I am referencing]

**Note** that the class is `public` <s>and this dll in the image was built in a `release, AnyCPU` configuration.</s> (update addressing comments: same issue regardless of build configuration, no `if #DEBUG` flags present anywhere in `NugetPackage.sln` and I have quadruple checked that the DLL being referenced is the one I am building - timestamps and all)

- In a `Separate.Project.csproj`, I am currently referencing the above dll directly.

**The Problem**

In Visual Studio, intellisense can see ValidationException in a `debug` configuration, but intellisense *can't* seem to see it in a `release` configuration, breaking my build - and I have no idea why this would be.

[image: image of debug config seeing ValidationException]

[image: image of release config NOT seeing ValidationException]

The error message is

> Namespace of types specified on **the Imports 'My.Namespace.ValidationException' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found**. Make sure the namespace or type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element doesn't contain aliases.

- I have at least 1 public member
- How do I verify a lack of "contained aliases"?

Does anyone have any idea why I would be seeing this?

How do I make Visual Studio happy so I can build again?

Comment: maybe this member has an `if DEBUG` tag in source code.

Comment: Also a possibility is you're using an old version of the release DLL.  Triple check that the DLL you're using has the expected modified date and/or version.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, but I've verified all of this - post updated to reflect that.

Comment: Make sure the dll is present in Release folder, and check the "Copy Local" property of the reference is set to True

Comment: I bet you simply not including that dll in release build...

Comment: VS2015 is the first release to feature Roslyn in this area and many bugs are known. Find a spare machine and try VS2017 RC. Microsoft might have solved it there.

Comment: Please create a simple demo, which can reproduce the issue, then share it to us via OneDrive. In addition, if it is vb.net project, please check the following solution. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234657.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on the sample, but, unfortunately, this isn't manifesting itself in my "hello world" version of the same setup (Same Ninject, Same .NET, Same MVC version, etc.). I will update this when I have one.